# Creating a new tablespace for index

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to create a brand-new (extra) tablespace for indexes. How can i do that?
What is the query? As far as i know first i have to create data file for that new tablespace but i don't know how...

Please help!

Comment: And accept the answer you find useful!

Comment: Did you bother reading the manual before posting?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to this is: don't. There was a myth some time ago that separating tables and index into different tablespaces was a good thing for performance reasons, which is not true. The increased maintenance and monitoring effort for handling multile tablespaces is almost never worth it, so unless you need to do something advanced like use transportable tablespaces you're almost certainly better off keeping it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Create your tablespace by:

```
create tablespace ts_indexes
datafile '/dbf1/ts_indexes.dbf' 
size 32m 
autoextend on 
next 32m maxsize 2048m
extent management local;
```

and then create new indexes in this tablespace by

```
create myIndex on myTable(field1, field2) tablespace ts_indexes;
```

and move existing indexes to this tablespace by

```
alter index myIndex rebuild tablespace ts_indexes;
```

Answer (score 1):

DDL is pretty straightforward.  The command to create a tablespace is easy to guess: `create tablespace`.

The Oracle documentation is online, comprehensive and free.  It even has examples.  [Find it here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7003.htm#i2231734)